# NHibernate and runtime expression

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I write access permission checker for entity obtain from db.
I have declared base rule class:

```
abstract class AccessRule
{
    private Func<object, Entities.User, bool> _canViewCompiledExpression;

    public abstract Expression<Func<object, Entities.User, bool>> RawCanEditExpression { get; }
    public abstract Type ObjectType { get; }
    public Expression<Func<object, bool>> CreateCanViewExpression(AccessContext accessContext, Entities.User user)
    {
        var entityArgument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "arg1");
        var userExpression = Expression.Constant(user, typeof(Entities.User));
        var body = Expression.Invoke(RawCanViewExpression, entityArgument, userExpression);

        return (Expression<Func<object, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(body, entityArgument);
    }
   }

  abstract class AccessRule<T> : AccessRule
    where T : Entity
  {
    public override Type ObjectType => typeof(T);

    public abstract Expression<Func<T, Entities.User, bool>> CanViewExpression { get; }
    public override Expression<Func<object, Entities.User, bool>> RawCanViewExpression => ExpressionHelper.BoxExpression(CanViewExpression);    
   }
```

And this is helper for convert Expression> to Expression>:

```
public static Expression<Func<object, Entities.User, bool>> BoxExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, Entities.User, bool>> expression)
{
    var objParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "arg1");
    var userParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entities.User), "arg2");

    var convertExpression = Expression.Convert(objParameter, typeof(T));

    var body = Expression.Invoke(expression, convertExpression, userParameter);
    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, Entities.User, bool>>(body, objParameter, userParameter);

    return result;
}
```

now, for example one rule, for one item:

```
public override Expression<Func<Entities.Order, Entities.User, bool>> CanViewExpression
        => (obj, user) => obj.Owner == user;
```

now I apply my expression (wrapped to specification class) for query to DB. I extract all conditions from expression (such Expression>, Expression>, MethodCallExpression and UnaryExpression) based on this code https://github.com/rjperes/DevelopmentWithADot.NHibernateSpecifications/blob/master/DevelopmentWithADot.NHibernateSpecifications/SpecificationExtensions.cs

and apply this to Query<> method.

I check result expression by compile it to Func and invoke on each items on database. all ok. 
but then i execute query on real connection i catch NullReferenceException in NHibertante core code.

after investigation i found that exception generated in NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionKeyVisitor.VisitConstantExpression method because _constantToParameterMap is null but used without any checks:

```
protected override Expression VisitConstantExpression(ConstantExpression expression)
{
    NamedParameter param;

    if (_constantToParameterMap.TryGetValue(expression, out param) && insideSelectClause == false)
```

null passed from NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereJoinDetectors.VisitMemberExpression method

```
var key = ExpressionKeyVisitor.Visit(expression, null);
```

I used NHIbernate 4.1.1

can anybody help with this problem?

**UPDATE 1**
this is debug view of result expression:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Boolean]>(System.Object $arg1) {
    .Invoke (.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`3[System.Object,Project.Entities.User,System.Boolean]>)(
        $arg1,
        .Constant<Project.Entities.User>(Project.Entities.User))
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`3[System.Object,Project.Entities.User,System.Boolean]>(
    System.Object $arg1,
    Project.Entities.User $arg2) {
    .Invoke (.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`3[Project.Entities.Order,Project.Entities.User,System.Boolean]>)(
        (Project.Entities.Windfarm)$arg1,
        $arg2)
}

.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`3[Project.Entities.Order,Project.Entities.User,System.Boolean]>(
    Portal.Domain.Entities.Windfarm $obj,
    Portal.Domain.Entities.User $user) {
    .Call($obj.Owner).Equeal($user)
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
after some experiments i found that error occurred only if i try access user inside rule... i.e if i replace check with expression, which does not contains access to user all work fine. so problem is in constant expression, but i can't understand why and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally i found solution. i did not found any reason for this behaviour...
first, i was was check expression which generated by my code and equivalent expression writed in code. main difference that my expression contains invoke of other expression, which invoke other expression (*we need to go deeper*), but in coded expression no nested items.

so i write some expressionvisitor: first for change argument of expression and convert it to original type in expression and second for replace parameter of expression with constant.

and now all work perfectly!